# Unable to find system image for mobile in API 25 (Android 7.1.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

[image: Screenshot]

Where are system images (either ARM or intel) for mobile profile in API 25? It is visible for API 24.

Answer (score 0):

You could see them on the image below
[image]

Comment: That was my point , they are visible for API 24 but not for API 25 , though not checked with latest updates.For me it worked when I just selected Google APIs for API 25